# Is it possible to have in-line display of amp-img?

Tags: amp-html

The following code displays only the first image.  The second image is nowhere to be found:

```
<div>
    <amp-img layout="fixed" width="100" height="200" style="display:inline-block;" src="~/Content/images/foo1.png" />
    <amp-img layout="fixed" width="100" height="200" style="display:inline-block;" src="~/Content/images/foo2.png" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, You can use inline css in AMP. In place of inline css, use class for better approach.

Example : [Click Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EpMZzM)

**CSS Code :**

```
 <style amp-custom>
    .your-class { display:inline-block; }
  </style>
```

**HTML CODE :**

```
<amp-img class="your-class" src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/F00/FFF" width="100" height="100" layout="fixed"></amp-img>
  <amp-img class="your-class" src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/F00/FFF" width="100" height="100" layout="fixed"></amp-img>
  <amp-img class="your-class" src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/F00/FFF" width="100" height="100" layout="fixed"></amp-img>
```

**Full Code** :

```
<!--
## Introduction

An AMP HTML tutorial - learn the different building blocks of an AMP HTML file. AMP HTML is entirely built on existing web technologies. It achieves reliable performance by restricting some parts of HTML, CSS and JavaScript. To make up for those limitations AMP HTML defines a set of custom elements for rich content beyond basic HTML. This samples shows what's necessary to create a valid AMP HTML file.
-->
<!-- -->
<!-- Doctype declaration is required. -->
<!doctype html>
<!-- This tells everyone that this is an AMP file. `<html amp>` works too. -->
<html ⚡>
<!-- ## Head -->
<!-- -->
<head>
  <!-- The charset definition must be the first child of the `<head>` tag. -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title> Hello World</title>
  <!-- The AMP runtime must be loaded as the second child of the `<head>` tag.-->
  <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
  <!--
    AMP HTML files require a canonical link pointing to the regular HTML. If no HTML version exists, it should point to itself.
  -->
  <link rel="canonical" href="https://ampbyexample.com/introduction/hello_world/">
  <!--
    AMP HTML files require a viewport declaration. It's recommended to include initial-scale=1.
  -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
  <!--
    CSS must be embedded inline.
  -->
  <style amp-custom>
    .your-class { display:inline-block; }
  </style>
  <!--
    The AMP boilerplate.
  -->
  <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style><noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>
</head>
<!-- ## Body -->
<!-- -->
<body>
  <!--
    Most HTML tags can be used directly in AMP HTML.
  -->
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <!--
    Certain tags, such as the `<img>` tag, are replaced
    with equivalent or slightly enhanced custom AMP HTML tags (see
    [HTML Tags in the specification](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-html-format.md)).

    You can use the [ AMP Validator ](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/validate.html) to check
    if your AMP HTML file is valid AMP HTML. Simply
    add `#development=1` to an AMP URL. Validation errors will be printed in the Javascript console.
    You can try it with this website which is build with AMP.

    Check out the [other examples](/) to learn more about AMP.
  -->


  <amp-img class="your-class" src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/F00/FFF" width="100" height="100" layout="fixed"></amp-img>
  <amp-img class="your-class" src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/F00/FFF" width="100" height="100" layout="fixed"></amp-img>
  <amp-img class="your-class" src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/F00/FFF" width="100" height="100" layout="fixed"></amp-img>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed instructions.  I am really puzzled because I first tried your answer, and it worked; then I switched inline style, and it also worked.  I do not know why it did not work yesterday.